# Terraform - range can't iterate over argument

Tags: terraform, kubernetes-helm

I tried to install helm chart of metric-server for EKS:

```
resource "helm_release" "metrics-server" {
  name = "metrics-server"

  repository = "https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/metrics-server/"
  chart      = "metrics-server"
  namespace  = "kube-system"
  version    = "3.10.0"

  set {
    name  = "metrics.enabled"
    value = false
  }
  set {
    name = "args"
    value = "--kubelet-insecure-tls"
  }
}
```

And have this error on after `terraform apply`:

```
│ Error: template: metrics-server/templates/deployment.yaml:59:27: executing "metrics-server/templates/deployment.yaml" at <.Values.args>: range can't iterate over --kubelet-insecure-tls
│ 
│   with helm_release.metrics-server,
│   on alb-controller.tf line 72, in resource "helm_release" "metrics-server":
│   72: resource "helm_release" "metrics-server" {
```

is there a way to pass this argument via terraform?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error is actually thrown by Sprig within Helm and not by Terraform, and pertains to Helm usage. This is because the Helm chart is expecting a value of type `list` and instead a value of type `string` is passed. However, the Terraform Helm provider requires a `string` type for the value for the `set` block (corresponding to the `-set` CLI argument with a literal string value), so we must use the `set_list` block instead. Updating the usage to pass a type `list` to Helm instead:

```
set_list {
  name  = "args"
  value = ["--kubelet-insecure-tls"]
}
```

This might not seem clear from the error message by the way, but the key part of the error message:

> <.Values.args>: range can't iterate over...

heavily implies (`range` function, `Values`) that the Sprig templating engine is expecting a `list` type when the Helm chart is rendered after inputs.

Comment: I had already tried
 │ Error: Incorrect attribute value type
│ 
│   on alb-controller.tf line 86, in resource "helm_release" "metrics-server":
│   86:     value = ["--kubelet-insecure-tls"]
│ 
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "value": string required.

Comment: @hellb0y77 yes I forgot there is also a Terraform Helm provider issue here that will surface once my initial fix is applied; answer updated

Comment: Same error, Error: template: metrics-server/templates/deployment.yaml:65:27: executing "metrics-server/templates/deployment.yaml" at <.Values.args>: range can't iterate over ['--kubelet-insecure-tls']

Comment: `['--kubelet-insecure-tls']` deserializes from YAML and unmarshals to a `[]string` which is the expected input type for `range`. Is there any extra information outside of the question that would explain the error message despite the correct usage?

Comment: I've resolved with `set_list` (https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/helm/latest/docs/resources/release#set_list), value is `value = ["--kubelet-insecure-tls"]`. Thanks Matt